# CSS sprite map cut-out fragment background

Tags: css

I have a sprite map. In that sprite map there is 1x1px fragment that I need to use to create a background for an element (i.e. repeated).

Does CSS alone provide a solution for that? I am interested even if it is futuristic and will work only in IE12. For those who don't know what a sprite map is, I've attached an example.

https://static.anuary.com/9429dc4e7a395b6443ae58919f1416523a9a798dd54931cb0e5ed70c582766a4/public/images/sprite.png.

Comment: According to discussion below, this is a hypothetical issue rather than a practical question.

Comment: That's an issue that has a solution but the solution is not the preferred one. That's not the meaning of "hypothetical".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a particular method that will let you clip a portion of an image to tile it as the background of an element. Since you only have a 1px x 1px fragment, why don't you use the standard `background-color` property or keep a separate graphic for this purpose? I prefer the `background-color` CSS property since you seem to be dealing with a solid color.

You can also go to [CSS3.info](http://www.css3.info/preview/) to see what's coming.

Comment: 1x1 was only a theoretical example. In real life, it can be anything like 1x100px with repeat-x. I know I could simply keep this bit out of sprite, but that's not what the question is about.

Comment: What's more, it doesn't seem to be planned for CSS4 either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using CSS `before` or `after` pseudo elements instead of using placeholder tags

```
.icon::after {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    content:" ";
    width:21px;
    height:24px;
    background:url(images/icons.png) -1000px -1000px no-repeat;
}
.icon::after {
    background-position: -14px -24px;
}
```